# Loop through dynamic xml tree to flatten it

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, tree, key

I want to make a stylesheet and use xslt/xpath to loop through my tree but I cant do the basics with this xml. Is this xml workable for xslt/xpath?

I want to loop through the exams by examId and check the examType

```
<data>
    <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
        <string key="planCode">01267 COE-EN/2014-08-01</string>
        <string key="planName">01267 COE-EN</string>
        <map key="exams">
            <string key="examId">00131105</string>
            <string key="examType">Kwalificatie</string>
            <string key="examName">90404 S Interact. vormgev.</string>
            <array key="exams">
                <map>
                    <string key="examId">00162650</string>
                    <string key="examType">Kwalificatie</string>
                    <string key="examName">90402 S Interact. vormgev.</string>
                </map>
                <map>
                    <string key="examId">00162640</string>
                    <string key="examType">Kwalificatie</string>
                    <string key="examName">90403 S Interact. vormgev.</string>
                </map>
            </array>
        </map>
    </map>
</data>
        
XSLT for what its worth...
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/data/map/string/@key ">
            <test>Test</test>
        </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Edit;
The answer helped me a lot and I could finally address the elements and attributes. I think it was because I didnt use the namespace xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
-----------
```

Comment: **Any** XML can be processed by Xpath/XSLT. Please ask one question at a time and include your attempt and the expected output. For grouping, see: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info.

Comment: Edited and changed to one question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That path, given the namespace declaration on the map element, can only work if you use a wildcard `/data/*:map/*:string/@key` or if you declare e.g. `xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"` in your stylesheet and use e.g. `/data/fn:map/fn:string/@key` or declare `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"` in the stylesheet and use `/*:data/map/string/@key` or `/*/map/string/@key`.

To flatten, use `//` as in `/data//*:string[@key = 'examType']`

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your last line. It works! Thanks to you I can go through the maps and find the appropiate keys when needed. I now need to find a way to go through all the subnodes of the group-by planCode.

Comment: Hi Martin, the last bit was sorted too and was easy after the namespace. thanks!